# How prevent user to change form input value from browser debug tools?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I would like to create a HTML form ,the user can input his name and submit, but the user does not fill in the name input, the system will not submit and show the error message in alert box.

Here is my code about form.php

```
<form name="myForm" action="b.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()">
</form>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

and submit successful,the information will go to this page b.php
b.php

```
    <?php
echo $_POST[fname];
?>
```

But When the user use browser debug tools(like chrome),They can change form input "name" "id" "class" .etc value, In this case, when the user change the form name value, the form can submit without fill in the name.

any idea to solve this problem.....or use javascript to Validation is not a good choice????? Thanks[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you heard of server side validation?

Comment: You can actually loop all forms. Dont specify the name of the form in validation. Just check all forms on the document. I will not do this personally, Ill just do to a back end validation.

Comment: You can never stop people from modifying the form. Anyone can save the HTML, modify it and then post it through cURL instead and any JS validation etc will be useless. JS validation is just a convenience for the user (not needing to post the data to the server to get hints on invalid fields etc.). You will _always_ need to validate it on the server as well. Basically, _never_ trust anything that comes from the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server side validation will handle this. Return the page back to the form if the input values is empty or anything.